# Extract tar file and preserve the permissions in php without using exec function

Tags: php, permissions, extract, tar

The current server that I'm using has the exec function disabled. Is it possible to use php script to extract tar and preserve the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PharData`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) class:

Example: `Create a tar`

```
$phar = new PharData('test.tar');
// add all files in the project
$phar->buildFromDirectory('/path/to/files');
```

Example: `Unpack a tar`

```
$phar = new PharData('test.tar');
// add all files in the project
$phar->extractTo('/path/to/files');
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it doesn't preserve the permissions of the extracted files from when they were before the compression. Or I just didn't know how to use this PharData? Which in the code you give get the permissions of the extracted files?